# GPG error: public key is not available when trying to setup PHP environment on Windows

Tags: php, linux, docker, debian

I am trying to setup a PHP Docker environment on windows.

When executing
`docker-compose up -d --build` and `docker-compose exec webserver-dev2 composer install -d /var/www` I get eventually this error:

```
=> ERROR [webserver-dev2  5/12] RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git zip unzip libpng-dev libjpeg-dev  6.0s
// ...
5.128 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
5.185 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
5.255 Ign:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
5.370 Err:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
5.370   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.10.132 80]
5.450 Ign:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main all Packages
5.540 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main all Packages
5.600 Err:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
5.600   404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.10.132 80]
5.608 Fetched 8666 kB in 5s (1678 kB/s)
5.608 Reading package lists...
6.006 W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 112695A0E562B32A NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853
6.006 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease' is not signed.
6.006 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
6.006 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
6.006 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
6.006 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9
6.006 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' is not signed.
6.006 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
6.006 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
6.006 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.130.132 80]
6.006 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.10.132 80]
6.006 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.10.132 80]
6.006 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git zip unzip libpng-dev libjpeg-dev" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.3.1-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y git zip unzip libpng-dev libjpeg-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ && docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql exif mbstring

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN pecl install xdebug-3.1.5
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

COPY ./php/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
COPY ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
```

For certifying the public keys I have already tried importing them with Kleopatra, but that didn't help. What should I do?